# ¿Por qué no se guardan los cambios que le hice a algunas variables?

Tags: c++, poo, lista, variables

Con este metodo intento cambiar los atributos de cada avion de la lista, pero no se guardan los cambios hechos aquí.

```
void avion::despegar(list<avion>::iterator itAv, int IDpista){
    avion b; aeropuerto n;
    int a=700; float i=0;

    list <aeropuerto>::iterator itAero = l_Aero.begin();

    b=*itAv;
    while( b.vel_vuelo < 275){
        Sleep(a);
        system("cls");
        b.vel_vuelo =i;  i++;
        if(a >= 150) { a=a-38; }
        if(b.vel_vuelo >= 265){
            b.altura=b.altura+0.01;
        }
    }
    Sleep(8000); // Tiempo de espera mientras el avión se aleja, para volver a usar la pista.
    while( itAero != l_Aero.end() ){
        n = *itAero;
        if( n.ubicacion == b.ciudad_origen )
            n.disp_pista[ IDpista - 1 ] = 0; // De nuevo queda disponible la pista usada.
        itAero++;
    }
    b.volar(itAv);}
```

Tengo una lista de objetos tipo avión, cuando intento cambiar los atributos de cada avión de la lista desde un método de esa clase, al terminar de ejecutarse quedan los atributos de cada avión como al principio, no se guardan los cambios. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
avion b;

b=*itAv; // <<--- copias el objeto
```

El comentario es bastante descriptivo. En esa línea estás **copiando** el estado del objeto almacenado en la lista en otro objeto diferente, `b`. Como son objetos diferentes el uno no sabe de la existencia del otro y no interactuarán de forma mágica... Dicho con un ejemplo: haces un jarrón, creas un molde y a partir de ese molde creas un segundo jarrón. Después coges el jarrón original y lo haces añicos contra el suelo... misteriosamente el segundo jarrón no sufrirá ningún daño.

Lo que tu estás buscando es trabajar con referencias:

```
avion & b = *itAv;
```

Eso sí, nota que las referencias hay que inicializarlas según se declaran... y una vez inicializadas no se pueden volver a inicializar.